# JS logs in Firefox, not Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, webkit, gecko

I have a function that works perfectly in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Any help?

```
$('[data-label="DropButtonPanel"]').click(function () {

    if ($('[data-label="StickyButtonGroup"] [data-label="Initial"]').css('visibility') == 'visible') {
        console.log("dropped");
        ... other stuff...  
    }

    else if ($('[data-label="StickyButtonGroup"] [data-label="Stuck"]').css('visibility') == 'visible') {
        console.log("not");
        ... other stuff...          
    }

});
```

The console logs perfectly in Firefox, but not at all in Chrome.. Any ideas what I could be missing? Thanks!

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint to see if it is called? And you can inspect to see what the code is doing?

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing with `console.log`? It logs in FF not in Chrome..

Comment: Have you never set a break point and walk through the code? https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints

Comment: No. But really thats kinda irrelevant. The question is why this works in FF not in Chrome.. Something wrong with the handler? Does webkit define `data-label` differently than gecko, etc.. Thanks for any input

Comment: Well it would show if they are being called. And you would be able to tell if it is finding the elements and such. Debugging 101 stuff. Do you have them filtered?

Comment: No this is the whole code (minus the 'other stuff' part). Works in FF not in Chrome when testing across browsers. No logging in the console. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56239/discussion-between-epascarello-and-nick-b).